# Drupal Content Type with Hundereds of fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a site where users can suggest a restaurant / Bar. The form will have hundreds of  form fields, ex  Bears can be selected and in bears there will be several brands and each brand will have the prices for Mug, Bottle, Half-pint, Pint, Jug, Bucket of 5, Tower, each will be having 2 prices one is happy hour and other is regular. Once the user data is submitted, admin will approve it and depending on such data we should build the front-end(Bears Section, Spirits Section, etc..) of the site.

What will be the beast possible way to build the form with CCK. The mockup can be viewed at http://indiantourplaces.com/mockup.gif

Comment: You might want to rethink having users fill out a form with hundreds of form fields. Most users wont be able to complete such a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Drupal 7 only, but it sounds like http://drupal.org/project/properties could be helpful.

It is basically a single field that consists of an unlimited amount of properties (key value pairs) grouped into categories. Categories/Properties can either be added dynamically or it can be limited to predefined templates.

Additionally, entities with attached properties can be compared.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be wise to leave it to admins to keep a beer list or spirit list up to date. You should consider having your site users make such a list for you by taking advantage of the Drupal Taxonomy functionality. You could have a beer brand field that would populate a beer brand vocabulary.

Btw it's "beer" not "bear" a bear happens to be a type of beast :P

Comment: OP's form is a beast, so perhaps the usage is correct! (Besides, who remembers how much drinks cost the morning after?)

Answer (score 1):

I think i might be interested in that module
http://drupal.org/project/webform